# Concurrency for requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I have a python script and I'm sending post requests to same url with different data(different ids). I have to send requests for each id and check them continuously to see if there is a change. I'm handling it with iterating an "ids" list with for loop and sending request for each id and then iterating the list again and again.

But I want to check every one of them for every 10 seconds max and if I have 1000 ids in the list, its getting longer to check first id again. I can solve this by running 10 parallel scripts to check 100 ids with each script. Is there any alternative you would suggest? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean literally running 10 parallel scripts, then yes, you improve upon this with multithreading from a single script.

Comment: yes I mean it. thanks, I'll look into multithreading.